# Is it fine to use the word "completed" when we talk about an object instead of a process?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, semantics

I have a small script to back up some of my files. It works completely silently and it doesn't provide any success or error messages, even if something is wrong.

The only message window popping up in the very end. The current text is:

> Execution of the script has been completed. Please note that the script doesn't provide any success or error messages.

The first sentence sounds too formal to me, so I would change it in the following way:

> **The script has been completed.** Please note that it doesn't provide any success or error messages.

I want to know whether the second version of the first sentence is semantically correct. (I think the answer is "no", and strictly speaking, it says that the *programmer* has finished *writing* the script.)

I also want to know which version of the first sentence sounds more convenient, more natural for native speakers.

Comment: The second version is not correct. Neither one is convenient. I sure don't want a dialog box telling me every time I run the script that the script provides no feedback.

Comment: For technical users, the original is fine; however, I don't like the word "script" for general computer users.  It is too technical.  Consider something like:  "The XXXXX process/file/program has finished running, but please note it does not notify you if any errors are encountered."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: **The script has been completed** sounds wrong because it is in the passive voice.  It means that *something else* has finished the script.  In the first sentence, the passive voice is fine, because the execution has been completed by something else (the script, or maybe the entire computer system).

I think your original "Execution of the script has been completed" is fine, but if you want something less formal, you could just say "The script has finished."

Comment: Shouldn't "execution" also be defined? **The** execution of **the** script...

Comment: Or it could just say "Finished." in the dialog.  The context means we don't need so much explaining.

Comment: I would be happy with 'the script has terminated, exited, ended, or finished'.